# Why is the difference between these two t-tests so big?

Tags: r, t-test, p-value, simulation

I am using a t-test to find out whether the mean of a sample ($1.05$) with a sample size of $100$ is significantly different from a given mean ($1.2$). The standard deviation should be $0.5$:

```
round(2*pt((1.05-1.2)*sqrt(100)/.5,df=100-1),3)
[1] 0.003
```

The next thing I am doing is to simulate the exact same parameter setup 10.000 times, do the t-test each time and at the end calculate the mean of all p-values:

```
v <- w <- m <- s <- numeric(1e4)
for (i in 1:1e4){
  rats.drug <- rnorm(100,1.05,.5)
  m[i] <- mean(rats.drug)
  s[i] <- sd(rats.drug)
  v[i] <- t.test(rats.drug,mu=1.2)$p.value
  w[i] <- 2*pt(abs((mean(rats.drug)-1.2))*sqrt(100)/sd(rats.drug),df=100-1,lower=F)
}
round(mean(v),3)
[1] 0.035
round(mean(w),3)
[1] 0.035

round(mean(m),2)
[1] 1.05
round(mean(s),1)
[1] 0.5
```

**My question**
It strikes me as very strange that this time the value is more than a whole order of magnitude bigger ($0.003$ vs. $0.035$)! How can this be - I suspect a silly mistake on my side...

**Edit**
I did some additional experiments and it doesn't seem to be a mistake. Because the distribution of the p-values is extremely skewed the median seems to work a lot better than the mean but I still don't fully get why.

Comment: Regarding efficiency: Set `v <- w <- m <- s <- numeric(1e4)` to avoid growing the objects. Pre-allocation will make your code much faster. Regarding your question: So, your question is why the distribution of the simulated p-values is very skewed? In principle all values between 0 and 1 are possible. Large values are much less likely, but they can occur. That's what you are seeing.

Comment: Could it be that the observed difference is due to the fact that you haven't specified the non-centrality parameter `ncp` in `pt()` function? Just a guess.

Comment: @Roland: Concerning the efficiency part I updated the post - Thank you. The question is not why the p-values are skewed but how to aggregate them so that you get the right theoretical value. Obviously the mean doesn't work (why?), the median works better but I don't know if this is the right way to do it and why.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: I don't think so because I am only replicating the p-value calculation of the t-test function. Both give the same, but "wrong" results.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarification. Unfortunately, I don't have any more ideas at this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the relationship between $t$ values and $p$ values is highly nonlinear, you observe a skewed distribution of $p$ values.

First, we calculate the "true" base value of $t$ and the corresponding $p$ value.

```
t_base <- (1.05 - 1.2) * sqrt(100) / .5
p_base <- 2 * pt(-abs(t_base), df = 100 - 1)
```

Note that I modified the calculation of the $p$ value. Your approach can lead to $p > 1$.

Now we repeatedly sample 100 values from $N(1.05, 0.5)$ and run a t-test. This simulation command returns a two-row matrix `sim_res`. The first row includes the $t$ values, the second row includes the $p$ values.

```
set.seed(1)
sim_res <- replicate(1e4, {rats.drug <- rnorm(100, 1.05, 0.5)
                           res <- t.test(rats.drug, mu = 1.2)
                           c(res$statistic, p = res$p.value)})
```

The following figure displays the distribution of $t$ values together with the base value (red bar).

```
plot(density(sim_res["t", ]), main = "Distribution of t values")
abline(v = t_base, col = "red")
```

[image]

As you can see, the true $t$ value corresponds to the mean of the simulation-based $t$ values. Furthermore, the distribution is symmetrical.

However, there is a nonlinear relationship between $t$ and $p$ values. The following figure displays the relationship for $\mathrm{df} = 100 -1$.

```
curve(2 * pt(-abs(x), df = 100 - 1), from = -4, to = 4,
      xlab = "t value", ylab = "p value",
      main = "Relationship between t and p value",
      sub = bquote(df == 100 - 1))
```

[image]

Due to this relationship the symmetric distribution of $t$ values does not result in a symmetric distribution of $p$ values but a highly skewed distribution. The following figure displays this distribution together with a red bar indicating the true $p$ value.

```
plot(density(sim_res["p", ], from = 0), main = "Distribution of p values",
     xlim = c(0, 0.1))
abline(v = p_base, col = "red")
```

[image]

The median is indeed a much better statistic for this skewed distribution. It closely matches the true $p$ value.

```
median(sim_res["p", ])
# [1] 0.003389245
p_base
# [1] 0.003415508
```

In the simulated data, approximately 50% of the $t$ values are more negative than the true value. Therefore, approximately 50% of the $p$ values are higher than the true value. (And vice versa.)

Comment: Thank you very much - this clarifies a lot. When sampling the t-statistics and calculating the p-value on their mean (2*pt(mean(t),df=100-1)) afterwards it is much better!

Comment: Apparently there is a problem with `density` (possibly the default bandwidth?). The plot shows a non-zero density for negative p-values which is not possible.

Comment: @Roland Right. I modified the code. Now the density is estimated for nonnegative values only.